# select only one attribute from php multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, select, multidimensional-array

Supposedly I have an array like this:

```
$shop = array( array("name"=>"Tom", "level"=> 1.25 ),
               array("name"=>"Mike","level"=> 0.75 ),
               array("name"=>"John","level"=> 1.15 ) 
             );
```

How do I make an array  with all name values and the keys being the position of theri original array. I know I could iterate through, and put in another array, but are there any functions?

Sorry if I was confusing. My desired output would be:

```
array(0=>"Tom",1=>"Mike",2=>"John");
```

So basicaly what select does in sql.

Comment: Can you show desired output?

Comment: Ah now I get it. Working on answer.

Comment: in array we cant have same key twice.

Comment: may be just [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Comment: You could use `array_walk`, but that iterates through the array as well.  No matter if you do it manually or with a function, you're going to have around the same computational value no matter what you chose (well, if you efficiently walk through the array yourself, that is ;) )

Comment: @StasGrin `array_keys` will give `(0,1,2, etc)` as the keys of the array is just going to be the index, where as the `values` will be the array you want to modify.

Comment: @Jon seems like truth. so only full array-walking can work..

Comment: @Jon thanks, I was interested in effiency, but it seems like it is imposible not to iterate through.

Answer (score 5):

As of PHP 5.3.0 you can use this:

```
$result = array_map(
    function($x) {
        return $x['name'];
    }, $shop);

print_r($result);
```

Prior to 5.3.0 you can use [create_function](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.create-function.php) for callback.

Answer (score 2):

Since php 5.5, you can use

```
$names = array_column($shop, 'name');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$shop = array( array("name"=>"Tom", "level"=> 1.25 ),
               array("name"=>"Mike","level"=> 0.75 ),
               array("name"=>"John","level"=> 1.15 ) 
             );
$newArr = array();

foreach($shop as $key=>$val){
$newArr[$key] = $val['name'];
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: @sirwilliam it's not the same as yours - for example, you can't loop through `$shop['name']` as that index doesn't exist.

Answer (score -2):

You can with `foreach`

```
<?php

$shop = array( array("name"=>"Tom", "level"=> 1.25 ),
               array("name"=>"Mike","level"=> 0.75 ),
               array("name"=>"John","level"=> 1.15 ) 
             ); 

$newar = array();
foreach($shop as $subarr){
    $newar[] = $subarr['name'];
}

print_r($newar);

?>
```

Comment: You should probably test things before you post them. ^^ Also, the author said they new how to loop it themselves and were looking for an alternate solution.

Comment: Of course it does - it's practically the same as Deepu's answer now, just removing the key. ^^

Comment: I was still working on it. Don't you make a mistake sometimes!? PS I was the first who answered I just made a little mistake. Shoot me now.The answers is good now and I stuck with -3 all fine. You win!!!

Comment: It's not about being the first to answer, it's about being the first to answer with actual usable code. ^^  It's not a contest really, but the first answer you post is what people see first, and your first example caused errors that took 8 minutes for you to update; meaning that people saw an answer that was impossible to use for 8 minutes on this topic which seems to have gotten a bit of attention. ^^ (I'll change my vote on the answer because you did finally get it correct - but first impressions are what matters with answers. ^^)